# A enquiry about NetBeans generated RESTful Web Service POST path and more

Tags: java, android, json, rest

I'm new to RESTful. So NetBeans can generate RESTful Web Service from entity class, database etc. I think it is cool to master it as it will be stressful to hand code every web service.

Can I ask what should be the path of a POST request to "create" method? And the Caller class (listed below) takes 3 parameters to construct it(see constructor below) (I will pass the 3 parameters from my Android client). But the "create" method takes Caller as a whole. What to do?
Does " @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})" indicate that the method consumes only xml or json, so I have to wrap the 3 parameters into a json object to POST?

And do I have to another a method path annotation for method? such as @Path("/create")? Because there are many other methods (GET, DELETE etc). I really don't know the path of POST request to "create" method.

My attempt would be, (after adding Path annotation for "create" method - @Path("/create")) http://my laptop's IP:8080/AndroidRESTful2/com.erikchenmelbourne.entities.caller/create?id=xxx&number=xxx&information=xxx

I am fairly new, so any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
@Stateless
@Path("com.erikchenmelbourne.entities.caller")
public class CallerFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Caller> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "AndroidRESTful2PU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public CallerFacadeREST() {
        super(Caller.class);
    }

    @POST
    @Override
    @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public void create(Caller entity) {
        super.create(entity);
    }
```

Caller Class has constructors and I will use the 3rd one

```
public Caller() {
    }

    public Caller(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Caller(Integer id, String number, String information) {
        this.id = id;
        this.number = number;
        this.information = information;
    }
```